# Team Foundation plugin for Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio, tfs

I want to move from Eclipse to Android Studio. In Eclipse I use a plugin for Microsoft Team Foundation Server. In Android Studio I downloaded a plugin called TFS Integration from JetBrains but it doesn't work (apparently it is only supported in "Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition".

I can't move to Android Studio without integration with TFS. How do I get integration with TFS?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have TFS in Android Studio at the moment, because AS is based on the free edition of intellij and TFS is based on the ultimate edition, as you said. So Jetbrain is selling a solution, therefore google can't fork it and make it free :)

You can use [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661) or [GitTF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/10/23/team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-idea.aspx

The plugin is in preview with an anticipated release in early 2016.
It seems that plugin lacks support of Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC): only Git is supported.

For TFS version control try this one [Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=androidstudio)

**UPDATE**
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services supports TFS Integration (TFS Version Control and Git) with Android Studio and all community and enterprise versions of Jet Brains IDEs.

Comment: The plugin crashes Android Studio.

Comment: @Questioner which one?